# How to access the vertices of a path in Gremlin through Java?

Tags: gremlin

I'm using Java to access Gremlin.  I have the following lines of code for creating a path between two vertices in an already created graph:

```
//begin simple path finding
        Vertex fromNode = g.V().has("name", "i2").next();
        Vertex toNode = g.V().has("name", "state1").next();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        g.V(fromNode).repeat(both().simplePath()).until(is(toNode)).limit(1).path().fill(list);
```

However, at this point I"m stuck.  I can print out the list using list.toString() and I get the vertices that (I believe) are on the path.  However, I now want to get those vertices themselves, access and potentially mutate their data.  For instance, it isn't enough to know that v[32] is on the path if I can't access the ID 32 itself.

I should mention that I'm a bit new to this so please let me know if I'm using outdated/incorrect practices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ended up with a list filled with `Path` objects. I think what you're looking for is the `unfold()` step ([see the docs](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#unfold-step)) so you can unroll/flatten out *the elements in path* to put into the list. Here's a Gremlin Console session showing it:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV("name", "i2").as("a").addV("name", "state1").addE("to").from("a").toList()
==>e[4][0-to->2]
gremlin> fromNode = g.V().has("name", "i2").next()
==>v[0]
gremlin> toNode = g.V().has("name", "state1").next()
==>v[2]
gremlin> l = new ArrayList()
gremlin> g.V(fromNode).repeat(both().simplePath()).until(is(toNode)).limit(1).path().fill(l)
==>[v[0],v[2]]
gremlin> l = []; g.V(fromNode).repeat(both().simplePath()).until(is(toNode)).limit(1).path().fill(l)
==>[v[0],v[2]]
gremlin> l = []; g.V(fromNode).repeat(both().simplePath()).until(is(toNode)).limit(1).path().unfold().fill(l)
==>v[0]
==>v[2]
gremlin> l[0].getClass()
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerVertex
gremlin> l[0].property("name", "j3") // mutate the vertex's name
==>vp[name->i3]
gremlin> g.V(fromNode).valueMap(true).toList()
==>[id:0,name:[j3],label:vertex]
```

Comment: fill(l) does not work from gremlin console. any suggestions for [my question that is similar to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212299/printing-fetching-vertex-values-from-a-path) ???    *Cannot set readonly property: list for class: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.VertexProperty$Cardinality*

Comment: When you are running in the Gremlin Console, `list` is a static import from `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.VertexProperty$Cardinality`, so you can't use it as a variable name. That's why in my example above uses `l` rather than `list`. If you attempt to do `list = []` or `list = new ArrayList()` the error message you mentioned is shown.

Answer (score 1):

You should have access to these through list you're using on the `fill` step. The `toString` method won't print out the properties. If you just want to see those, you can call `valueMap()` instead of `fill` at the end of your traversal. If you'd like to iterate over all of the vertices and get the properties, you can use the `properties` method. If you want to get a specific property, you can use the `property(key)` method. The rest of what you'd need is in [the API docs](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.2.4/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Vertex.html)

Comment: I'm a bit confused, I'm afraid.  in the last step I fill a list.  But what is it filled *with*?  Vertices?  On the other hand, if I call valueMap(), what is the data type returned?

Comment: Yes. It is filled with

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm still missing something. At the last step, if I print out the class of list.get(0), it gives me ImmutablePath.   However, I can't seem to do any operations on that path, since Java is convinced that it's just an Object.  I'm clearly missing something important...

Comment: Hm, it seems I had to do a monstrous cast: ` System.out.println(((Vertex)((ImmutablePath)list.get(0)).get(0)).value("name"));`  That...doesn't seem quite right

Comment: Maybe declare your ArrayList as an `ArrayList<Vertex>`?

Comment: It actually seems to require a Traversal...I guess I can just write a function that converts.  It seems a bit hacky to me but oh well, I don't really need outstanding functionality at this point.

Comment: What requires a traversal? Value map is the only thing I mentioned that requires a traversal

Comment: When I use the fill method, I need to supply it with list.  However, if I change list's type of ArrayList<Vertex> it says that it requires a Traversal and can't convert ArrayList<Vertex> to Traversal.