# Printing/Fetching Vertex values from a path

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

Just getting started with gremlin.

Printing out all the Vertex values worked out fine

```
gremlin> g.V().values()
==>testing 2
==>Cash Processing
==>Sales
==>Marketing
==>Accounting
```

I was able to find all the directly connected path between my Vertices.

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('Process')
.repeat(both().simplePath())
.until(hasLabel('Process'))
.dedup().path()
==>[v[25],v[28]]
==>[v[25],v[26]]
==>[v[26],v[27]]
==>[v[26],v[25]]
```

**Now am trying to print out the values in the path like ['Sales', 'Accounting'] instead of [v[25],v[28]]**

Not been able to figure out a way yet

---

Already tried and **failed** with

1. Unfold: Does not get me 1-1 mapping

   gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('Process').repeat(both().simplePath()).until(hasLabel('Process')).dedup().path().unfold().values()
   ==>Cash Processing
   ==>Accounting
   ==>Cash Processing
   ==>Sales
   ==>Sales
   ==>Marketing
   ==>Sales
   ==>Cash Processing
2. Path seems to be of a different data-type and does not support .values() function

   gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('Process')
   .repeat(both().simplePath())
   .until(hasLabel('Process'))
   .dedup().path().values()

org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ImmutablePath cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element

3. Tried the following google searches and didnt get the answer

   - [gremlin print a path](http://google.com/#q=gremlin+print+a+path)
   - [gremlin get values in a path](http://google.com/#q=gremlin+get+values+in+a+path)
   - and few more word twisting
4. Found one at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45391065/1897935) that was for java but that didnt work for me

   l = []; g.V().....path().fill(l)

(but cant create list, Cannot set readonly property: list for class: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.VertexProperty$Cardinality
)

---

*I have running it on Gremlin console (running ./gremlin.sh)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [by step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#by-step) to modulate the elements inside the path. For example by supplying `valueMap(true)` to `by` you get the properties of the vertices, together with the vertex labels and their ids:

```
gremlin> g.V().repeat(both().simplePath()).times(1).dedup().path().by(valueMap(true))
==>[[id:1,name:[marko],label:person,age:[29]],[id:3,name:[lop],lang:[java],label:software]]
==>[[id:1,name:[marko],label:person,age:[29]],[id:2,name:[vadas],label:person,age:[27]]]
==>[[id:1,name:[marko],label:person,age:[29]],[id:4,name:[josh],label:person,age:[32]]]
==>[[id:2,name:[vadas],label:person,age:[27]],[id:1,name:[marko],label:person,age:[29]]]
==>[[id:3,name:[lop],lang:[java],label:software],[id:6,name:[peter],label:person,age:[35]]]
==>[[id:4,name:[josh],label:person,age:[32]],[id:5,name:[ripple],lang:[java],label:software]]
```

I used the modern graph which is one of TinkerPop's *toy graphs* that are often used for such examples. Your output will look a bit different and you may want to use something else than `valueMap(true)` for the `by` modulator. The [TinkerPop documentation of the `path` step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#path-step) itself contains two more advanced examples for `path().by()` that you might want to check out.